# Cómo selecciono diferentes etiquietas con el mismo nombre en XSLT?

Tags: xml, xsl, xslt

Tengo el siguiente XML:

```
<document any="2015">
    <comarca>
        <nom>Alt Camp</nom>
        <centres>
            <public>8</public>
            <privat>2</privat>
        </centres>
        <professors>
            <public>223</public>
            <privat>34</privat>
        </professors>
    </comarca>
    <comarca>
        <nom>Alt Empordà</nom>
        <centres>
            <public>15</public>
            <privat>7</privat>
        </centres>
        <professors>
            <public>642</public>
            <privat>94</privat>
        </professors>
    </comarca>
</document>
```

Y la salida tiene que quedar tal que así:

```
<document>
   <comarca nom="Alt Camp">
      <centres public="8" privat="2"/>
      <professors public="223" privat="34"/>
   </comarca>
   <comarca nom="Alt Empordà">
      <centres public="15" privat="7"/>
      <professors public="642" privat="94"/>
   </comarca>
</document>
```

Mi XSL lo transforma bien pero solo transforma para la primera etiqueta y lo repite en la siguiente.

Transformacion.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/document">
        <document>
            <xsl:for-each select="/document/comarca">
                <comarca>
                    <xsl:attribute name="nom">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/document/comarca/nom/text()"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <centres>
                        <xsl:attribute name="public">
                            <xsl:value-of select="/document/comarca/centres/public"></xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="privat">
                            <xsl:value-of select="/document/comarca/centres/privat"></xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </centres>
                    <professors>
                        <xsl:attribute name="public">
                            <xsl:value-of select="/document/comarca/professors/public"></xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="privat">
                            <xsl:value-of select="/document/comarca/professors/privat"></xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </professors>
                </comarca>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Supongo que el error está en la ruta de XPATH en el atributo *select* del *for-each* pero no se porqué.

El documento xsl no puede ser que sea específicamente para esas dos etiquetas, tiene que ser "general", es decir, que valga para esas dos etiquetas *comarca* y si hubiera más en el XML.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Usa rutas relativas, ya que estas pivoteando con `/document/comarca`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/document">
        <document>
            <xsl:for-each select="/document/comarca">
                <comarca>
                    <xsl:attribute name="nom">
                        <xsl:value-of select="nom/text()"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <centres>
                        <xsl:attribute name="public">
                            <xsl:value-of select="centres/public"></xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="privat">
                            <xsl:value-of select="centres/privat"></xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </centres>
                    <professors>
                        <xsl:attribute name="public">
                            <xsl:value-of select="professors/public"></xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="privat">
                            <xsl:value-of select="professors/privat"></xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </professors>
                </comarca>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
``
```